# Change font color in dracula theme in android studio

Tags: android-studio

[image: Darcula color settings]

How can I change font color in dracula theme in android studio? cause with color's font now, the color less bright.

Answer (score 0):

1. File->Settings->Editor->Colors & Fonts
2. Download themes in .jar format from  web. Then go to File -> Import Settings and choose the file downloaded
3. Bonus
   But this theme might add more colors to your coding life.
   [image: Monokai Theme]

Link with more details:
http://envyandroid.com/monokai-theme-in-android-studio-and-intellij/

Answer (score 0):

[image: Press <code>CTRL+ALT+S</code>]

Inside Settings goto: **Editor > Colors & Fonts > Java** there you can change the color of any attribute.